# How to add and overlap two images with X,Y cordinates

Tags: java, android, coordinates

[image]

I want to add two images on an activity and then I want to relocate image-2 over image-1
Is there any possibility of using x-axis and y-axis or any other method to accomplish this task?

**Updated Requirement :**
 My requirement is that I will take some user input and based on those inputs, the image will move. As you can see the rows in the attached image, I want move pin image from one row to another as per inputs.

Comment: You could make a custom view, which simply darws all specified images in the `onDraw`

Comment: see if this helps:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29624446/how-to-merge-save-image-after-overlaying-other-image/29626275#29626275

Comment: Use a `RelativeLayout`. Drag the `ImageView`'s so they overlap, or use `layout_margin-top`/`left`, or `gravity`. I have an example using `NetworkImageView`'s, but in xml it's not very clear to see what the result will be.

Comment: Thank you guys for suggestions, but my requirement is I will take some inputs and on behalf of those inputs image will move, as you can see rows in attached image I want move pin image from one row to an other as per inputs

Comment: I have done my task by this method public  Bitmap overlay(Bitmap bmp1, Bitmap bmp2, float x, float y) {

    DisplayMetrics metrics; 
    metrics = new DisplayMetrics();        
    ((Activity) contrContext).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
    Bitmap bmOverlay = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp1.getWidth(), bmp1.getHeight(), bmp1.getConfig());
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmOverlay);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bmp1, new Matrix(), null);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bmp2, x, y, null);
    return bmOverlay;
}

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way to accomplish this is by Placing two images in the middle of frame layout, and in java after getting reference to those images, use the method `bringtofront();`

eg: `ImageView image2=findviewbyID(R.id.image2);`

```
image2.bringtofront();
```

Comment: `FrameLayout` is a more reliable option than using RelativeLayouts for margin-positioning. Good call